# Is there an elementary proof of Cayley-Bacharach that holds in the case where points are not necessarily distinct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, conic-sections, elliptic-curves, intersection-theory

Silverman and Tate in *Rational Points On Elliptic Curves* (and Tao [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/pappuss-theorem-and-elliptic-curves/)) discuss a proof of the [Cayley-Bacharach Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Bacharach_theorem) in the case where two conics intersect at nine **distinct** points. The proof uses Bézout's theorem, but other than that is elementary.

Is there a way to modify the aforementioned proof (or, present some other simple proof) that can prove Caley-Bacharach in the case where the nine intersection points of the conics are not necessarily distinct (that is, the number of intersection points counting multiplicity is nine, but not counting multiplicity is less than nine)?